# Are there any preventative measures I should employ after my MacBook was seemingly bricked?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave

Yesterday while working on my 12" 2017 MacBook I got a warning from system preferences that I couldn't shut down because it wasn't responding.

I force shut down the laptop and it would no longer turn on. 
After trying to reset the SMC with no success and not finding other resources to solve the issue, I set up an appointment with the Apple store for the next day and went to sleep. When I got up, the laptop just turned on.

Now I'm worried that I just got lucky and will have the problem come back. Besides backing up data, what are other procedures, updates, or other precautionary steps I can take to give me the best chance of preventing this happening again?

Answer (score 1):

- Proceed to take it to an apple store for checking
- Run Apple Diagnostics on your Mac:
  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731
- Run "/applications/utilities/disk utility" to check out the drive.

[image]
You will need to answer two prompts.

Run ends with:

[image]
This picture is from High Sierra.  user3439894 has provided additional links.

Should you find a problem, you can boot in recovery mode ( hold down command + r then power on your machine ). Look for Disk Utility under Utilities. Run "repair disk".

Comment: Apple Hardware Test is for Macs introduced before June 2013 and the OP is running a 2017 MacBook. See: [How to use Apple Diagnostics on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT202731) Also, don't just say e.g. "run /applications/utilities/disk utility to check out the drive", at the least, give some guidance. Have a look at [Verify a disk using Disk Utility on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/verify-a-disk-dskutl35916/mac) and [Repair a disk using Disk Utility on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/repair-a-disk-dskutl1040/mac)

Comment: I updated the article.